# Why customizing cell in UITableView is receiving error: hasn't received initWithFrame: or initWithCoder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I followed a tutorial on youtube and I followed all the steps very carefully three times. but I received this error:

```
2014-09-27 04:02:42.248 JourneyTracker[6667:306214] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requesting the window of a view 
(<CustomeCellTableViewCell: 0x8362f6f0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 0 0); 
transform = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = (null)>) with a nil layer. This view probably hasn't received initWithFrame: or initWithCoder:.'
            *** First throw call stack:
            (
                0   CoreFoundation                      0x00e0edf6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
```

I have searched many related questions and most of them, they forgot to init a button etc. But as you can see in following I have two label and init them:

```
@implementation CustomeCellTableViewCell{

    UILabel *_nameValue;
    UILabel *_weightValue;

}

- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if(self)
    {
        CGRect nameLableRect = CGRectMake(0, 5, 70, 15);
        UILabel *nameLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:nameLableRect];
        nameLable.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        nameLable.text = @"name";
        nameLable.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [self.contentView addSubview:nameLable];


        CGRect weightLableRect = CGRectMake(0, 26, 70, 15);
        UILabel *weightLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:weightLableRect];
        weightLable.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        weightLable.text = @"weight";
        weightLable.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [self.contentView addSubview:weightLable];

        //Add content
        CGRect nameValueRectangle = CGRectMake(80, 5, 200, 15);
        _nameValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:nameValueRectangle];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_nameValue];


        CGRect weightValueRectangle = CGRectMake(80, 5, 200, 15);
        _weightValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:weightValueRectangle];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_weightValue];

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void) setName:(NSString *)n
{
    if (![n isEqualToString:_name])
    {
        _name = [n copy];
        _nameValue.text = _name;
    }
}

- (void) setWeight:(NSString *)w
{
    if (![w isEqualToString:_weight])
    {
        _weight = [w copy];
        _weightValue.text = _weight;
    }

}

@end
```

The strange thing is that when I was debugging above `awakeFromNib` never called and in tutorial I was following on youtube there was no "awakeFromNib" in his code!!

I have debugged this code line by line. First it goes into `UITableViewController` and the it goes to customize class (above) and when it comes back to `UITableViewController` it crashes. I have commented with <<<>>>> in my code where it crashes.

And here is my `UITableViewController`:

```
@implementation ListJourneyController

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellTableIdentifier";


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 //Some implementation to modify array        

    UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    [tableView registerClass:[CustomeCellTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return numberOfRow;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//<<<<<This point it goes to customize class and when it comes back it crashes>>>>>>
    CustomeCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    Journey *rowData = items[indexPath.row];
    cell.name = @"afshar";
    cell.weight = @"Hila";
    return cell;

}
```

**Update**
After solving this problem now both items appear in same field!
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never call the `super` implementation inside your CustomeCellTableViewCell class. That's why you're getting the error. Add the call to `super initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier` and you'll be good to go.

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Now do your setup code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the only problem I have and is not related to this question, is that name and weight will be written in same field on top of each other. Very strange!

Comment: From the looks of that picture, it seems like they're being written to the right locations. Your tableView is just behind your status bar. You can change the frame of the tableView to not start at the origin (put it 20 points lower on the y axis), or you can just embed the whole viewController inside a UINavigationController and the system will take care of the status bar. Also you should probably left align those labels since they have different text lengths

Comment: Thanks. I just made a silly mistake! nameValueRectangle and weightValueRectangle are located in same location. I probably need to sleep as here is 4am. Thanks again ;)